# How can I remove "||" in strings as str_replace_all function is not available?

Tags: r

I want to remove `||` in strings in R. How can I do this?

I tried to use str_replace_all function,
but it did not work.

Example:

```
[As-is]            
||20180307||     

[To-be]
20180307
```

Comment: Try `str1 <- "||20180307||";
readr::parse_number(str1)#[1] 20180307`

Comment: if the `||`are always at the beginning you could use `substr()`, for example: `x <- "||20180307||";  substr(x, 3, nchar(x)-2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `base R` option would be `gsub`

```
gsub("[|]+", "", str1)
```

Or specify the `fixed = TRUE` (more efficient) as @MichaelChirico mentioned in the comments

```
gsub("|", "", str1, fixed = TRUE)
```

---

Or using `parse_number` from `readr`

```
library(readr)
parse_number(str1)
#20180307
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "||20180307||"
```

Comment: `gsub('|', '', str1, fixed = TRUE)` should be better no?

Answer (score 0):

Without using `Regex` but R base `read.table`

```
> read.table(text="||20180307||", sep="|", colClasses = "numeric")[,3]
[1] 20180307
```